# Instantiating inner class of class

Tags: java

Basically I have a java class Foo with a generic T and a inner class Foo2 which is using this generic T somehow like the following example:

```
public class Foo<T>
{
  public class Foo2
  {
    private T t;
    public void setObject(T t)
    {
       this.t = t;
    }
  }
}
```

After try and error (until the compiler don't throw a warning or error) how to create an instance of this inner class Foo2 I came up with the following:

```
Foo<String> foo = new Foo<String>();
Foo2 foo2 = foo.new Foo2();
```

The second line `foo.new Foo2();` is something which is new for me and I don't know what exactly I'm doing here. For me it is somehow clear, that an instance of the class Foo2 has to know what class T is but the syntax `foo.new` is new for me. What am I doing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An inner class is a class declared inside another one without using the `static` keyword. An instance of an inner class has to belong to an instance of the outer class. For example, a good example of an inner class might be

```
public class School {

    public class Pupil {

    }
}
```

Every `Pupil` has to belong to a `School` so you cannot construct a `Pupil` instance without a school. You can do

```
School school = new School();
School.Pupil pupil = school.new Pupil();
```

The second line creates a new `Pupil` belonging to a particular `School`.

Inside the `Pupil` class you get the school the pupil belongs to by doing `School.this`. You can use fields of the `School` class by doing `School.this.someField`.

If you want to be able to create `Foo2` instances without an instance of `Foo` you can write

```
public static class Foo2
```

instead. In most cases, you probably should use static nested classes in preference to inner classes.

Comment: Nice example and code. Mentioned should be that a Pupil may use fields and methods of School.this, and School.this ittself.

Comment: @JoopEggen Good idea, thanks. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 3):

The `foo.new Foo2()` syntax has nothing to do with generics. It's a way to instantiate an inner class by supplying an instance of the enclosing class.

Answer (score 1):

Inner classes (as opposed to static inner classes) are associated with a particular instance of the outer class.

`foo.new` associates the new instance of the inner class with the instacne of the outer class from the `foo` variable.

This has nothing to do with generics.

Comment: So if the inner class Foo2 can modifiy members of the outer class Foo then the modifications will be done in the instance foo when I called foo.new Foo2() ?